How to debug GWT?
I am making game in LibGDX and have problem with understanding where error is. Game works fine on desktop, but in GWT SuperDev it stuck on loading screen with infinity number of errors:
...
Minefield: Replacing 3 13 with EnterCell 
Minefield: [Unknown.AXc(html-0.js), Unknown.cYc(html-0.js), Unknown.new jYc(html-0.js),
 Unknown.tch(html-0.js), Unknown.Agd(html-0.js), Unknown.Pj(html-0.js), Unknown.Kj(html-0.js),
 Unknown.new Jj(html-0.js), Unknown.new dj(html-0.js), Unknown.dl(html-0.js), Unknown.tm(html-0.js),
 Unknown.eu(html-0.js), Unknown.qC(html-0.js), Unknown.iB(html-0.js), Unknown.<anonymous>(html-0.js)]
...

Is there a way to look into compiled GWT code and find where exactly it is broken? Or how can i get verbose logs in browser?
Compiling GWT doesn't show any errors or warnings
Here is codeblock where something goes wrong:
private void placeCells(Class<? extends FieldCell> cellType, int count) {
        int placed = 0;

        while (placed < count) {
            int row = StaticShit.random.nextInt(rows);
            int col = StaticShit.random.nextInt(cols);
            //find cell at row, col
            Gdx.app.debug("Minefield","Replacing "+row+" "+col+" with "+ClassReflection.getSimpleName(cellType));
            Cell<? extends FieldCell> cell = getCellCell(row,col);
            if (cell.getActor() instanceof EmptyCell) {
                try {
                    FieldCell fieldCell = ClassReflection.newInstance(cellType);
                    fieldCell.setPosition(row, col);
                    placed++;
                    cell.setActor(fieldCell);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Gdx.app.debug("Minefield", Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));

                }
            }
        }
    }

I tried adding more logs and removing parts of code, but I want more convinent way to locate errors.

Did you set the extra module settings for reflection, needed by GWT?
See
https://libgdx.com/wiki/utils/reflection
Also the libGDX help has moved to Discord now.

Yes, I add it in  in core *.gwt.xml. It fixed this exact problem but there are others which I can't locate because stacktrace is incomprehensible. Can I do something with it?

On specifically Chrome browser you can step through the actual code with a local server as described here https://libgdx.com/wiki/html5-backend-and-gwt-specifics
